# Replacing stringgrid with listbox in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am trying to replace the `stringgrid1` and `stringgrid2` with `listbox1` and `listbox2` respectively.  Is their any way I can do it?  If `listbox` can not do may anyone suggest what I should use instead of `stringgrid` to display the information?  I'm a newbie to Delphi.

This is my code:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer;
begin
stringgrid1.ColWidths[0]:=20;
stringgrid2.ColWidths[0]:=20;
for i:=1 to 50 do begin
    stringgrid1.Cells[0,i]:=inttostr(i-1);
    stringgrid2.Cells[0,i]:=inttostr(i-1);
    stringgrid2.Cells[1,i]:='0';
end;
  stringgrid2.Cells[1,0]:='name';
  stringgrid1.Cells[1,0]:='extension';
  stringgrid1.Cells[2,0]:='format';
  stringgrid1.Cells[3,0]:='size';
  stringgrid1.Cells[4,0]:='date';
  stringgrid1.Cells[5,0]:='addres';
end;

procedure TForm2.StringGrid2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if (stringgrid2.Cells[1,stringgrid2.Row]<>'1024') and (stringgrid2.Cells[1,stringgrid2.Row]<>'0') then
  stringgrid1.Row:=strtoint(stringgrid2.Cells[1,stringgrid2.Row]);

end;
```

end.

```
Procedure HD;
var i:integer;
begin
   for i:=0 to 50 do begin
     form2.StringGrid1.Cells[1,i+1]:=TABLE[i].name;
     form2.StringGrid1.Cells[2,i+1]:=TABLE[i].format;
     if TABLE[i].tip then
           form2.StringGrid1.Cells[3,i+1]:='folder'
     else
           form2.StringGrid1.Cells[3,i+1]:='file';
     form2.StringGrid1.Cells[4,i+1]:=inttostr(TABLE[i].nach);
     form2.StringGrid1.Cells[5,i+1]:=inttostr(TABLE[i].razmer);
     form2.StringGrid2.Cells[1,i+1]:=inttostr(fat[i]);;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Since you have multiple columns you need a `TListView` in `vsReport` view style rather than a listbox.

Comment: how can put it in my code?just replace it

Comment: Have a look at these examples, and read the documentation. [ListItemSubItems](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/TListItemSubItems_(Delphi))  [ListItemsInsert](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/TListItemSubItems_(Delphi))

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's GREAT that you posted some code, but next time you ask a question, please be detailed about what you are trying to do with the code. Sample sentence: "I want to show the folders and file sizes and also want to display some pictures in the third column, but I don't know how to do that with TStringGrid".

Comment: Reposting David's links with the second one fixed (just in case): [ListItemSubItems](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/TListItemSubItems_%28Delphi%29), [ListItemsInsert](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/TListItemsInsert_%28Delphi%29).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `TListView` instead of `TStringGrid`.  Replace your `TStringGrid` components with `TListView` components, set their `ViewStyle` to `vsReport`, set up their `Columns` collections as needed, and then update your code as follows:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
var
  i: integer; 
begin 
  // NOTE: this can all be done at design-time so
  // you don't need to do it in code at runtime!
  ListView1.Colums[0].Width := 20; 
  ListView2.Colums[0].Width := 20; 
  for i := 0 to 49 do begin 
    ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := IntToStr(i); 
    with ListView2.Items.Add do begin
      Caption := IntToStr(i); 
      SubItems.Add('0'); 
    end;
  end; 
  ListView2.Columns[1].Caption := 'name'; 
  ListView1.Columns[1].Caption := 'extension'; 
  ListView1.Columns[2].Caption := 'format'; 
  ListView1.Columns[3].Caption := 'size'; 
  ListView1.Columns[4].Caption := 'date'; 
  ListView1.Columns[5].Caption := 'addres'; 
end; 

procedure TForm2.ListView2DblClick(Sender: TObject); 
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin 
  Item := ListView2.Selected;
  if Item = nil then Exit;  
  if (Item.SubItems[0] <> '1024') and (Item.SubItems[0] <> '0') then 
    ListView1.Selected := ListView1.Items[StrToInt(Item.SubItems[0])];
end; 

procedure HD; 
var
  i: integer; 
begin 
  for i := 0 to 49 do begin 
    with form2.ListView1.Items[i] do begin
      SubItems[0] := TABLE[i].name;
      SubItems[1] := TABLE[i].format; 
      if TABLE[i].tip then 
        SubItems[2] := 'folder' 
      else 
        SubItems[2] := 'file'; 
      SubItems[3] := IntToStr(TABLE[i].nach); 
      SubItems[4] := IntToStr(TABLE[i].razmer); 
    end;
    form2.ListView2.Items[i].SubItems[0] := IntToStr(fat[i]);
  end; 
end;
```

With that said, depending on how and when `TABLE[]` and `fat[]` are actually being filled in, you might be able to take this a step farther by setting the `TListView.OwnerData` properties to True to put the ListViews into virtual mode, and then use the `TListView.OnData` event to display your data dynamically.  That way, you can get rid of your `HD()` procedure completely, as your data does not need to be copied in the `TListView` itself anymore, it can be displayed from `TABLE[]` and `fat[]` directly instead, eg:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
var
  i: integer; 
begin 
  // NOTE: this can all be done at design-time so
  // you don't need to do it in code at runtime!
  ListView1.Colums[0].Width := 20; 
  ListView2.Colums[0].Width := 20; 
  ListView2.Columns[1].Caption := 'name'; 
  ListView1.Columns[1].Caption := 'extension'; 
  ListView1.Columns[2].Caption := 'format'; 
  ListView1.Columns[3].Caption := 'size'; 
  ListView1.Columns[4].Caption := 'date'; 
  ListView1.Columns[5].Caption := 'addres'; 
  //

  ListView1.Items.Count := 50;
  ListView2.Items.Count := 50;
end; 

procedure TForm2.ListView2DblClick(Sender: TObject); 
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin 
  Item := ListView2.Selected;
  if Item = nil then Exit;  
  if (Item.SubItems[0] <> '1024') and (Item.SubItems[0] <> '0') then 
    ListView1.Selected := ListView1.Items[StrToInt(Item.SubItems[0])];
end; 

procedure TForm2.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem); 
begin 
  Item.Caption := IntToStr(Item.Index);
  Item.SubItems.Add(TABLE[Item.Index].name);
  Item.SubItems.Add(TABLE[Item.Index].format); 
  if TABLE[i].tip then 
    Item.SubItems.Add('folder') 
  else 
    Item.SubItems.Add('file'); 
  Item.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(TABLE[i].nach)); 
  Item.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(TABLE[i].razmer))
end;

procedure TForm2.ListView2Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  Item.Caption := IntToStr(Item.Index);
  Item.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(fat[i]));
end;
```

Comment: I'm really tempted to downvote this for the simple reason that you've illustrated using `with` to a new programmer. :) (I'm not, BTW.) It would be far better IMO to show how to do it properly (without the `with`) instead, to make sure you don't introduce hard to track down problems for someone with no experience in solving them. (Or at least explain the potential problems and suggest doing it differently.)

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - TeamB how do i set their ViewStyle to vsReport...i have been trying but im not achieving it

Comment: `ViewStyle` is accessible in the Object Inspector when you drop and select a `TListView` at design-time. Or you can set it in code, eg: `ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport;`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - TeamB i did exactly what you told me to do but its giving me an error some like (expected '='but '(' found)its flashing on the procedure TForm2.ListView2DblClick(Sender: TObject);

Comment: Answered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752845/delphi-error-correction

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the StringGrid you can use a TListView with report style and multiple columns.

Comment: how can i achieve that...should i just replace it

Comment: For the OP's purposes which are to explore and learn delphi, this might be the easiest approach as it doesn't require installing any third party controls.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can show grid data in a listbox, but that is not an exercise for a newbie. The technique is based on `LB_SETTABSTOPS` message processing and described in [Ray Konopka's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1883577470). Using ListView is much simpler alternative.

Answer (score 1):

A listbox is intended to hold a single vertical list of enumerated values (provinces, credit card types, or genders), not a multi-column display with headings.

If you want something better, you should use a more powerful grid component, not a listbox.

You could also use TListView, but I do not recommend that approach for a new person. I have just spent a lot of time working with TListView in view style mode "vsReport", and I find it is even more limited than TStringGrid, for example, it provides no in-place edit support.

Instead, for a new person, I recommend you stay with the TStringGrid until there is something you need to do (which you have not specified!) that can't be done with TStringGrid, since for the trivial code you've shown, it seems TStringGrid does exactly what you want, and so it only sounds like you're making work for no benefit here.

What are you trying to do exactly? What problem is there with you TStringGrid code that you want do do something to change the control?

Comment: So, a different approach would be to select a different grid control, install it, and then change your code. Try it, and post how far you get.   There are many different grid controls out there, but not a lot are free and open source.  Try this one, for instance:  http://www.flex-graphics.com/Files/Free/GridView.zip

Answer (score 0):

as time would pass by - you'd probably like to add more features.
on of the best would be VirtualTreeView

- http://www.lischke-online.de/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview
- http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/source/checkout