# Fixing an error in a method declaration in a form in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid, tlistview

Why am I getting this error, I replaced a stringgrid with a listview, I then set it to viewstyle vsreport but I am getting an error like (expected '=' but '(' found) its flashing on this procedure below

```
procedure TForm2.ListView2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
```

this is my code

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Grids, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    ListView1: TListView;
    ListView2: TListView;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TForm2.ListView2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  // NOTE: this can all be done at design-time so
  // you don't need to do it in code at runtime!
  ListView1.Columns[0].Width := 20;
  ListView2.Columns[0].Width := 20;
  for i := 0 to 49 do begin 
    ListView1.Items.Add.Caption := IntToStr(i);
    with ListView2.Items.Add do begin
      Caption := IntToStr(i);
      SubItems.Add('0'); 
    end;
  end; 
  ListView2.Columns[1].Caption := 'name';
  ListView1.Columns[1].Caption := 'extension'; 
  ListView1.Columns[2].Caption := 'format';
  ListView1.Columns[3].Caption := 'size'; 
  ListView1.Columns[4].Caption := 'date';
  ListView1.Columns[5].Caption := 'addres'; 
end;

procedure TForm2.ListView2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin 
  Item := ListView2.Selected;
  if Item = nil then Exit;  
  if (Item.SubItems[0] <> '1024') and (Item.SubItems[0] <> '0') then
    ListView1.Selected := ListView1.Items[StrToInt(Item.SubItems[0])];
end;

end.
```

.

```
procedure HD;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 49 do begin
    with form2.ListView1.Items[i] do begin
      SubItems[0] := TABLE[i].name;
      SubItems[1] := TABLE[i].format;
      if TABLE[i].tip then
        SubItems[2] := 'folder'
      else
        SubItems[2] := 'file';
      SubItems[3] := IntToStr(TABLE[i].nach);
      SubItems[4] := IntToStr(TABLE[i].razmer);
    end;
    form2.ListView2.Items[i].SubItems[0] := IntToStr(fat[i]);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `Form2.` portion in the declaration of the event handler:

```
type 
  TForm2 = class(TForm) 
    Edit1: TEdit; 
    Edit2: TEdit; 
    ListView1: TListView; 
    ListView2: TListView; 
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
    procedure ListView2DblClick(Sender: TObject); // <-- here
  private 
    { Private declarations } 
  public 
    { Public declarations } 
  end;
```

Comment: sorry i had a typo error..the problem now is  its trying to compile but there is an error saying list index out of bounds

Comment: on which line exactly? you need to be more specific.

Comment: its on the reload procedure after the hd procedure,is it ok if i mail the small project to you?how can i attach it here?the code is quite huge...or should i just paste it here

Comment: http://www.filefactory.com/file/c10f5cb/n/fat16.rar its a fat16 model when try to enter the name of the file and its size then see what happens..also try to display the memory see whats is giving me

Comment: Did you even try using the debugger yet to watch exactly how your code is using the indexes?

Comment: how do i do that?im new to delphi how can i do it

Answer (score -1):

Why does the unit "end." appear within the following procedure:

```
procedure TForm2.ListView2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin 
  Item := ListView2.Selected;
  if Item = nil then Exit;  
  if (Item.SubItems[0] <> '1024') and (Item.SubItems[0] <> '0') then
    ListView1.Selected := ListView1.Items[StrToInt(Item.SubItems[0])];
end;
end.
```

Unless you're posting code from multiple units, move it to the end of the unit file.

Comment: The `end.` is not inside the procedure.